# What NTFS permissions for ApplicationPoolIndentity website?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7, ntfs

In my website's application pool, the identity is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Normally I would use "Network Service" and give read/modify rights to "Network Service" on the website file system. However, someone told me to use "ApplicationPoolIdentity" instead because the site will have their self contained permissions (so one site cannot update files of another when all under "Network Service").

What NTFS user should I use for providing read/modify permissions to a website's "ApplicationPoolIdentity" though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IIS AppPool\AppPoolName
```

Note that this might not be GUI-selectable or GUI-resolvable in the Object Picker with Windows 2008 (as opposed to R2), but should work from a command line, for eg, with ICACLS or similar.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use ICACLS on 2008.  Also, you can continue to use "Network Service" as you always have, you just need to enable the Medium Trust level for ASP in IIS.  That will only allow apps to work within their specific Virtual Directory.